# NoMethodError at /members undefined method `friend_id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Now I am trying to add "follow button" on my users' index page.

My goal is like... when users push the button once, the message beside the button turns "following". And he or she push it again, the message turns "not following". Default message is "not following".

And then I wrote the codes below but got an error message.Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

```
NoMethodError at /members undefined method `friend_id' for nil:NilClass
```

☆index.html.erb(members_controller)

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>写真</th>
    <th>名前</th>

    <th>分野</th>
    <th>場所</th>
    <th>経験</th>
     <th>Follow</th>
    <%# if Member.find(session[:user_id]).admin %>
    <%# end %>
  </tr>
<% @members.each do |member| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <% if member.provider %>
        <%=image_tag member.image ,:size=>'30x30'%>
     <% elsif member.avatar_file_name %> 
        <%= image_tag member.avatar.url(:thumb), :width =>'30px', :height =>'30px' %>
     <% else %> 
        <%= image_tag "love.png", :size=>'30x30'  %>  
     <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="/members/<%= member.id %>"><%= member.name %></a>
       <% if member.provider == "facebook" %>
           <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/<%=member.uid %>"> <%=image_tag "fb.png" ,:size=>'20x20'%>  </a>
        <% elsif member.provider == "twitter" %>
           <a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/<%=member.name %>"> <%=image_tag "twitter.png" ,:size=>'20x20'%>  </a>
       <% end %>
    </td>

    <td><%= member.field %></td>
    <td>
         <% if member.url.present? %>
           <%=link_to member.place ,member.url ,:target=>["_blank"] %> 
         <% else %>
          <%= member.place %>
        <% end %>  
      </td>
      <td><%= member.experience %></td>
      <td>
        <div class="onoff">
            <% unless session[:user_id] == member.id %>    
               <% if @isFr.friend_id == member.id %>
                  <%= link_to'off', {:controller => 'members', :action => 'index', :id =>
                  member.id}, class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%><br/>
                  ※following
                <% else %>
                   <%= link_to'on', {:controller => 'members', :action => 'index', :id =>
                  member.id}, class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%><br/>
                  ※not following
               <% end %>
             <% end %>  
         </div>
      <%#= member.friends.count %>
    </td>
     <% if Member.find(session[:user_id]).admin %>
         <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', member, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
     <% end %>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

☆members_controller

```
  def index
    if !checklogin? then return end 
     @members = Member.where("id >=1").order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).scoped
      if params[:name].present?
       @members = @members.where("name like ?" , "%" + params[:name] + "%")

      end

      if Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).exists? then
       Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).each do |f|
        f.destroy
        end
    else
       Friend.new({:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id =>params[:id].to_i}).save
    end


      @members.each do |m|
      @isFr = Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => 
      m.id ).first
      end


       respond_to do |format|
           format.html # index.html.erb
           format.json
        end 

  end
```

☆sessions_controller #session[:user_id]

```
 auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
member = Member.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])


   session[:user_id] = member.id
```

Comment: why the condition `where('id >= 1')` ?

Comment: It is a kind of substitute for all items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query must be returning blank AR

```
@members = Member.where("id >=1")
                  .order("created_at desc")
                  .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).scoped
```

And `@isFr` is eventually resulting in `nil`

```
  @members.each do |m|
  @isFr = Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => 
  m.id ).first
  end
```

Just a word of refactor you can do

`Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => @members.map(&:id)) .limit(1)`

But would be better if you think on the [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/association_basics.html) between your models. That way it will optimize with join queries

Comment: Thank you for you comment.I followed your instruction but faced an error message. undefined method `friend_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc4b4450670> And I checked the content of @isFr. >> @isFr
=> [#<Friend id: 140, member_id: 2, friend_id: 3, created_at: "2013-12-22 09:28:40", updated_at: "2013-12-22 09:28:40">]
This is array?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the instance var @isFr in your index action returns nil. That means the code `Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => m.id ).first` is returning nil.

You could do `<% if @isFr.try(:friend_id) == member.id %>` in your members#index view so that that you won't get the NoMethodError.

There's something wrong with the below code I found in your index action:

```
@members.each do |m|
  @isFr = Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => m.id ).first
end
```

The problem with the code above is that @isFr will only retain value of the last element in @members array. It's better to add a method in the Member model for that behavior like this:

```
#in app/models/friend.rb
scope :get_member_id, ->(member, user_id) { where(:member_id => user_id, :friend_id => member.id ).first.try(:friend_id) }
```

Then use it in your view like:

```
<% unless session[:user_id] == member.id %>   # below this line of code
  <% if Friend.get_member_id(member, session[:user_id]) == member.id %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I followed your instruction but got an error message.NoMethodError at /members
undefined method `friend_id' for #<Member:0x007fc4b8d73000>. member model doesn't have friend_id column. But member has_many friends on member.rb

Comment: Sorry about the earlier error on my part. I've edited my answer. Hope it works this time!

Comment: Thank you very much. But I encountered this after correcting the code in line with your instruction.
SyntaxError at /members
syntax error, unexpected tLAMBDA, expecting keyword_end

>> Friend
!! #<SyntaxError: /Users/aramak/railsprojects/SNS/app/models/friend.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tLAMBDA, expecting keyword_end
...ope :get_member_id, (member) -> { where(:member_id => sessio...
...                               ^>

Comment: Sorry about that! When declaring a lambda, the correct format is `->(member) { where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => member.id ).first.try(:friend_id) }`. I've edited my code to reflect that correction. :)

Comment: Thank you again. After the correction, I got this.NameError at /members
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<Class:0x007fc4b52c0cf0>

Could you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: I added sessions_controller on the question above.

Comment: Could you give me the backtrace for the error you experienced? It will help us to troubleshoot the problem. I think the problem is in friend.rb and edited the code to reflect the corrctions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who gave me hints, I made it with the code below.

☆index.html.erb(members_controller)

```
 <td>
        <div class="onoff">
            <% unless session[:user_id] == member.id %>    
                 <% if @Frids.include? member.id%>
                  <%= link_to'Off', {:controller => 'members', :action => 'index', :id =>
                  member.id}, class: "btn btn-midium btn-warning"%><br/>
                  ※既follow
                <% else %>
                   <%= link_to'On', {:controller => 'members', :action => 'index', :id =>
                  member.id}, class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%><br/>
                  ※未follow
               <% end %>
             <% end %>  
         </div>
      <%#= member.friends.count %>
    </td>
```

☆members_controller

```
def index
    if !checklogin? then return end 
     @members = Member.where("id >=1").order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).scoped

      if Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).exists? then
       Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).each do |f|
        f.destroy
        end  
      else
       Friend.new({:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id =>params[:id].to_i}).save
      end

      @Frids =Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id]).map{|x| x.friend_id}

       respond_to do |format|
           format.html # index.html.erb
           format.json
        end 

  end
```